# App crashes after embedding in navigation controller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios7

!(http://s10.postimg.org/8gy1q2rrt/question.png)
When i get to the last view controller on the right and press BACK button I Go back to the 1st controller not the second , i want to go back 1 step. (1>2>3). so i added navigation controller between them (don't know why ) , and app crashes when I want to go to the 3rd viewcontroller . all segues are PUSH. 
This is BUTTON #1 CODE. @"tevzeulimenu" is the ID of the tabbarcontroller.

```
- (IBAction)goMenu1:(id)sender {
UITabBarController *firstView = [self.storyboard     
instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tevzeulimenu"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:firstView animated:YES];
}
```

And this is code for segue:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"show1"])
{
    DetailMenuViewController *detailViewController =
    [segue destinationViewController];

    NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [self.tab1
                                indexPathForSelectedRow];

    long row = [myIndexPath row];

    detailViewController.detailMenu= @[_menu1Images[row],
                                       _menu1Names[row],
                                        _menu1Prices[row],
                                       _menu1Text[row]];
}
}
```

Help to solve this problem.  I want to go back from the 3rd view controller on the right(the last one) to 2nd when pressing back and not to the 1st.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8aa1170'

Answer (score 0):

You should use :

```
- (IBAction)goMenu1:(id)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"show1" sender:self];
}
```

Of course you have to add a `Segue` in your storyboard with the identifier : `show1`.

Hope that will help.

EDIT: In the context.

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply can you edit my code. as you have already figured out I'm newbie.

Comment: Ok here I'm newbie on stackoverflow but I think you just have to valid my answer.

Comment: it doesn't work because a) I used it in a wrong place b)it's not correct, so please can you edit my code. i replaced if statement with your code and it didn't help.

Comment: crashed when hiting button

Comment: you have to add a `Segue` in your `storyboard` with the identifier : show1